# OLEDB change connection error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, oledb, powerpivot, data-connections

I have done some investigation on this issue, but nothing works out. 
I am trying to change my PowerPivot connection. Im able to change Access source file, but on refresh it gives me an error, because the workbook(highlighted) connection string remains unchanged. See images.

[PowerPivot wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVpuG.png)

[Workbook connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HYs1.png)

I found this VBA code to change it manually, but it gives me 1004 error.

```
Sub NewConnection()

  ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Existing Connection name").OLEDBConnection.Connection = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Desktop\Category Reports\Access DB\Access.accdb;Persist Security Info=false"

End Sub
```

I have tried many codes and none of them works. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the source string in single quotes? I think the spaces would throw an error

Comment: Single quotes? How? Give an example please

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Existing Connection name").OLEDBConnection.Connection = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\user\Desktop\Category Reports\Access DB\Access.accdb';Persist Security Info=false"`

Comment: I don't see any difference between my code and yours. Anyway, it doesn't work =(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Access data base was corrupt, but it was not easy to identify. I have managed to create new data base and re-link it to my excel worksheet via PowerPivot.

Works great!